# Entity Framework Linq Filter Parent-Child Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Im currently trying to filter my query result for the `Menu` entity which has a self relation. My `Menu` model is like this:

```
public class Menu : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Menu Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And now I need to get the query result for `Menu` including their `Children` but with a condition, which contains the *child (or descendant)* that registered in `many-to-many` entity (*Role to Menu*). In the `RoleMenu` entity, I just keep the leaf node of the `Menu` belongs to a `Role`.

```
public class RoleMenu
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
}
```

What I've tried so far is this:

```
public IEnumerable<Menu> GetMenu(string roleId)
{
     return _dataContext.Menu
         .Where(m => _dataContext.RoleMenu.Where(rm => rm.RoleId == roleId).Select(rm => rm.MenuId).Any(mid => mid == m.MenuId))
         .Include(m => m.Children)
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Where(m => m.Parent == null)
         .ToList();
}
```

But, it doesn't bring the `hierarchy`, only the leaf nodes.

Comment: Try following : _dataContext.Menu.Where(m => _dataContext.RoleMenu.Any(md => (m.MenuId == md.MenuId) && (md.RoleId == mid))).ToList();